# RegEx - match the beggining of specified value using pattern in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm creating the simple type named `pathSimpleType` in my XML schema. It should be a string and should start with `../resources/`. I tried to achieve it with `<xs:pattern />` however it's not working since regular expressions in XSD are a little bit different.

Here is what I have tried so far and it's not working, could someone help me?

```
    <xs:simpleType name="pathSimpleType">
         <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="^\.\.\/resources\/(.*)"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the "^". Regex patterns in XSD are implicitly anchored, and "^" and "$" are not recognised as meta-characters (they represent themselves - a bad design mistake).